# jquery extract float point number with 2 decimal places

Tags: jquery, regex, point, floating

I want to extract a float number from a string with 2 or 3 decimal places after coma **without rounding (not toFixed)** in jquery

Examples (2 decimals)

```
'43,999999' => 43.99
'324324243,669' => 324324243.66
'0,229' => 0.22
'0,2' => 0.2 or 0.20
'0.9' => 0.9 or 0.90
```

Examples (3 decimals)

```
'43,999999' => 43.999
'324324243,669' => 324324243.669
'0,229' => 0.229
'0,2' => 0.2 or 0.200
'0.9' => 0.9 or 0.900
```

I've tried [-+]?([0-9]*,[0-9]+|[0-9]+) but doesnt work

Any regex expert? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upto two decimal places.

```
^(\d+)[.,](\d{1,2})\d*$
```

Replace the matched chars with `$1.$2`. For three decimal places, you need to use

```
^(\d+)[.,](\d{1,3})\d*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pY3oY1/1)

```
> '43,999999'.replace(/^(\d+)[.,](\d{1,2})\d*$/g, '$1.$2')
'43.99'
> '43,999999'.replace(/[.,](\d{1,2})\d*$/g, '.$1')
'43.99'
```

Comment: replace(/[.,](\d{1,2})\d*$/g, '.$1') should suffice.